# Webclient.DownloadFile Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, file, download

I am trying to download a file from https://webgis.dme.qld.gov.au/webgis/webqmin/shapes/epm.tar to save to my d:\ drive using the webclient. I get an error 
Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Just after the "Client.DownloadFile"

This is my first time using C#!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Project1
{
    class Class1
    {
        WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
        Client.DownloadFile("https://webgis.dme.qld.gov.au/webgis/webqmin/shapes/epm.tar", @"d:\epm.tar");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your code into a method:

```
namespace Project1
{
  class Class1
  {

    public void DownloadIt()
    {
        WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
        Client.DownloadFile("https://webgis.dme.qld.gov.au/webgis/webqmin/shapes/epm.tar",      @"d:\epm.tar");
    }
  }
}
```

Then to use it, you simply call the method from your console app or winform app:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.DownloadIt();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am now getting the following error:  The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have two files. Class1.cs which is                                                              namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Class1
    {

        public void DownloadIt()
        {
            WebClient Client = new WebClient();
            Client.DownloadFile("https://webgis.dme.qld.gov.au/webgis/webqmin/shapes/epm.tar", @"d:\epm.tar");
        }
    }
}

Comment: and program.cs which is:                                             using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.DownloadIt();
        }
    }
    }